# Image loading speed: host the image or pull from link?

Tags: image, performance, url, hyperlink, src

I'm in the process of building my website and have come across something I want your opinions on.

I've noticed that even though I've compressed my photos A LOT (18mb to 500kb or so) they take a while to load when I display them through my site. That being said, if I pull random photos from the web and use the link to display them, they load almost instantly.

With that being the case, would uploading all my photos to Flickr, then pulling the image URL and using that as my img src be better than using the actual file from my server as my img src?

Pros and Cons?

Obviously if Flickr ever went down I'd be hurting, but if it means that the other 99.99% of the time my photos load faster I'd be all for it.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually those images are hosted on a CDN, which means they are on multiple servers throughout the world, while images on your site are only on one. That's why theirs load faster.